# What is the meaning of interpolation technique as in "using an interpolation technique to deduce facts"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, writing, books

What is the meaning of **interpolation technique** as in [using an interpolation technique to deduce facts](https://burtoniana.org/biography/) (a book review)

> Rice, Edward.
> 1990.   Captain Sir Richard Francis Burton: A Biography.  New York, Scribner. Highly imaginative but dubious.  Sold well, but seems to
> have used an interpolation technique to deduce 'facts'.

I looked it up from https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interpolate, "to add something in the middle of a text, piece of music, etc." and from https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/interpolate, "to put additional words into a piece of writing"

So I would guess the meaning as the author adds his/her own words/imaginations/thoughts to facts. But on the other hands don't most (if not all) authors do that ? So what is an interpolation technique to deduce 'facts', e.g. in plain English? I also like to see an example of that.

BTW, this is a related question to my question on history SE site [What is a good biography of Sir Richard Francis Burton for ESOL readers?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/68846/what-is-a-good-biography-of-sir-richard-francis-burton-for-esol-readers)

Comment: You need to look at the math definition of "interpolation".  Simplistically speaking, it's having two points on a graph and calculating where a third point would fall.

Comment: [This](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/interpolation) definition from Webster's comes pretty close:  : *the process of calculating an approximate value based on values that are already known*

Comment: Oh this is a nice one. I added this https://www.thoughtco.com/extrapolation-and-interpolation-difference-3126301 to make interpolation more easy to understand in math term. But what about the the review I asked. What is the plain English of "used an interpolation technique to deduce facts" ?

Comment: @HotLicks Your simple definition needs sharpening up to refer to a calculated point **between** the other two. Your definition would also include extrapolation, which is when the calculated point lies outside the other two.

Comment: I am more curious why my question got downvoted?

Comment: @Anton - We're not talking about mathematical precision here.  It's an analogy.

Comment: @hotlicks Try (https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/interpolate): to add something **in the middle** of a text, piece of music, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Interpolation is a mathematical technique. A simple example is with a volume control on a sound system. If you know that one position is too loud and another position is too quiet, there is a position in between that is just right. We expect the volume to increase predictably as we adjust the control from the soft position to the loud position; putting numbers on the positions and the volumes would let us do it mathematically.

Interpolation doesn't always work. If two places have the same height interpolation would suggest that the land in between is also the same height, but there might be a mountain in between.

The phrase 'using an interpolation technique to deduce "facts"', probably means using interpolation and presenting the results as though they are true. Results obtained from interpolation are only true under certain conditions, so this is a criticism of the author. The criticism would be for not providing enough evidence to justify using interpolation.

The phrase might also mean presenting the results of interpolation as though they are new discoveries. When interpolation is valid and done correctly it only discovers consequences of the existing data; it cannot produce genuinely new discoveries. The phrase would still be a criticism, but it would be a criticism for presenting old information as though it was new.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. From the comments I got I already knew it was a math term. But what the plain English of that in the book review,  the author's judgement is inconclusive or simply he just make it up ?

Comment: I have added to my answer. The most likely meaning is that the author has effectively jumped to conclusions (by assuming that interpolation would be valid).

Comment: I think the reason I went too far was because I had not thought I would get an explanation from math point of view. I am reading a biography of Sir Richard Francis Burton and raised my question in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

> *Highly imaginative but dubious. Sold well, but seems to have used an interpolation technique to deduce 'facts'.*

These sentences are a brief review of Rice’s book.  In this case *interpolation* is not a mathematical technique for estimating an unknown value, but the presentation of information as factual that is really based on speculation, and is therefore, as the writer says, *dubious,* or unlikely to be verifiable.

One common fault in casually written biographies is that the author tells the reader how the subject feels or what he’s thinking, which the author has no way of knowing, especially when the author didn’t know the subject. This is a kind of interpolation (used metaphorically), although I’d use the term extrapolation.

Comment: Oh right, "extrapolation" seems more appropriate. lol Thanks!

Comment: Extrapolation is also a mathematical technique, and it basically assumes that a trend in the data you already have will continue into the data you don't have. To say that interpolation or extrapolation was used to produce something that is really the product of the writer's imagination is to be very softly critical of something that in my view would deserve much more severe criticism.

Comment: 'Speculation' seems a better choice of word for such a loose usage.